# Encryption Identification

Tags: encryption

I've downloaded a server applications and the registration password encryptions are looking like this(example):

```
y3CfIdk8ozzzbfE2uhzp9ViHz6E=
```

What kind of encryption is this? I want to create a web registration for my server and I don't know the encryption.

Comment: First of all you should make yourself aware of the fact that encryption and hashing are two completely different things (and for storing passwords, usually the latter gets used).

Comment: It's a Base64 encoded 20 byte value. The hex equivalent is CB709F21D93CA33CF36DF136BA1CE9F55887CFA1. 20 bytes match the output size of SHA-1. It's hard to say anything beyond that.

Comment: If you want to know how to hash passwords properly, look at [How to securely hash passwords? on security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords). Plain SHA-1 is a bad password hash.

Comment: I think the answers are clear now, but because it is unlikely to be of value to anyone else, I am closing as too localized.

Answer (score 1):

It's [Base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. It decodes to (in hex)
`70CB 219F 3CD9 3CA3 6DF3 36F1 1CBA F5E9 8758 A1CF`

Given that that's 20 bytes (160 bits), my guess would be that it's a [SHA-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) hash.

Likely there's no encryption involved. Passwords generally aren't encrypted.

Comment: Do you guys know any PHP function to make this hash?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you mention which applications / web server you are using. Application generally do not require their users to know which encyptin methodolgy is used.

Comment: I'm hosting an Aion gameserver and the registration is automatic by default (you go in game, enter username and password and if it's your first log in, it's an automatic registration). Now I want to disable it and make a registration over website with email verification and all but I don't know the PHP function for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "for this"? They're already encrypted when you get them, right? So why do you need a PHP function to do what's already done? (I think you have a misunderstanding about how password **hashing** works and are still confusing it with encryption.)